# PHP: por qué se modifica el valor de una variable que no se modifica durante la ejecución?

Tags: php, php7, datetime

Buenass... Tengo el siguiente código que sirve para que mediante un formulario el usuario ingrese una fecha de inicio,
una de final, un horario de inicio, uno de final y un intervalo de tiempo en minutos. Con esos datos creo una tabla en
MySQL en donde para cada fecha inserto un registro con los intervalos calculados. Para realizar las operaciones sobre las
fechas y horas uso la clase `DateTime`. Como verán, en el formulario pre-cargo los valores ingresados por el usuario. He
notado que los valores pre-cargados en el formulario luego del `submit` y de "la procesación" corresponden con los valores
finales de las variables `$start_date`, `$end_date`, `$start_time` y `$end_time` y no con los ingresados por el usuario a
pesar de que esas variables no se modifican.
Alguien me podría explicar por qué sucede eso?

A continuación dejo el código y la tabla (no sé para qué, pero la dejo igual).

El código:

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 90);
define("BBDD_CONN_DATA_FILE", "inc/bd.ini");
require("inc/bd.php");

$start_date = new DateTime("2023-06-12");
$start_date_aux = $start_date;
$end_date = new DateTime("2023-06-13");
$start_time = new DateTime("08:00:00");
$start_time_aux = $start_time;
$end_time = new DateTime("21:00:00");
$time_interval = new DateInterval("PT30M");
$hay_error_busqueda = false;
$error_busqueda = "";

if (isset($_POST['consultar'])) {
    $start_date = new DateTime($_POST['fecha_inicio']);
    $start_date_aux = $start_date;
    $start_time = new DateTime($_POST['hora_inicio']);
    $start_time_aux = $start_time;
    $end_date = new DateTime($_POST['fecha_fin']);
    $end_time = new DateTime($_POST['hora_fin']);
    $time_interval = new DateInterval("PT" . $_POST['intervalo'] . "M"); // in minutes

    // crear una tabla temporal?
    $query = "drop table if exists intervalos";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);
//    $query = "create temporary table intervalos(
    $query = "create table intervalos(
        id int not null auto_increment primary key,
        f_ini date not null,
        h_ini time not null,
        h_fin time not null)";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($query) ;

    if ($end_date < $start_date) {
        $hay_error_busqueda = true;
        $error_busqueda = "La fecha de fin no puede ser anterior a la fecha de inicio";
    }

    if (!$hay_error_busqueda) {
        $query = "insert into intervalos values ";
        while ($start_date_aux <= $end_date) {
            while ($start_time_aux < $end_time) {
                $query .= "(null, ";
                $query .= "'" . $start_date_aux->format("Y-m-d") . "', ";
                $query .= "'" . $start_time_aux->format("H:i:s") . "', ";
                $start_time_aux->add($time_interval);
                if ($start_time_aux > $end_time) {
                    $query .= "'" . $end_time->format("H:i:s") . "'";
                } else {
                    $query .= "'" . $start_time_aux->format("H:i:s") . "'";
                }
                $query .= "), ";
            }
//            $start_time_aux = $start_time;
            $start_time_aux = new DateTime($_POST['hora_inicio']);
            $start_date_aux->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
        }
    }
    $query = substr($query, 0, -2);
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);


    if ($hay_error_busqueda) {
        echo "<p>$error_busqueda</p>";
    }
}

?>
<h1>Buscar</h1>
<form action="lapagina.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label>Fecha de inicio: </label>
        <input type="date" name="fecha_inicio" value="<?=$start_date->format("Y-m-d");?>">
        <label>Fecha de fin: </label>
        <input type="date" name="fecha_fin" value="<?=$end_date->format("Y-m-d");?>">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label>Hora de inicio: </label>
        <input type="time" name="hora_inicio" value="<?=$start_time->format("H:i");?>">
        <label>Hora de fin: </label>
        <input type="time" name="hora_fin" value="<?=$end_time->format("H:i");?>">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label>Intervalo en minutos: </label>
        <input type="text" name="intervalo" value="<?=$time_interval->format("%I");?>" size="5">
        <input type="submit" value="consultar" name="consultar">
    </fieldset>
</form>

<?php
echo "<p>Tiempo de ejecución: " . (microtime(true) - $start) . "</p>";
```

La tabla:

```
+----+------------+----------+----------+
| id | f_ini      | h_ini    | h_fin    |
+----+------------+----------+----------+
|  1 | 2023-06-12 | 08:00:00 | 08:30:00 |
|  2 | 2023-06-12 | 08:30:00 | 09:00:00 |
|  3 | 2023-06-12 | 09:00:00 | 09:30:00 |
.....
| 25 | 2023-06-12 | 20:00:00 | 20:30:00 |
| 26 | 2023-06-12 | 20:30:00 | 21:00:00 |
| 27 | 2023-06-13 | 08:00:00 | 08:30:00 |
| 28 | 2023-06-13 | 08:30:00 | 09:00:00 |
| 29 | 2023-06-13 | 09:00:00 | 09:30:00 |
...
| 50 | 2023-06-13 | 19:30:00 | 20:00:00 |
| 51 | 2023-06-13 | 20:00:00 | 20:30:00 |
| 52 | 2023-06-13 | 20:30:00 | 21:00:00 |
+----+------------+----------+----------+
```

Mooochas graceas!

PD: si, debo hacer un ajuste fino a los rangos horarios, aunque ahora eso no es relevante.
PD2: si si, ya sé que debería actualizar a PHP8...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe al uso de referencias en PHP. En tu código, cuando asignas una instancia de la clase DateTime a una variable y luego asignas esa variable a otra variable, estás creando una referencia en lugar de una nueva instancia independiente.

Por ejemplo, en estas líneas de código:

```
$start_date_aux = $start_date;
$start_time_aux = $start_time;
```

Estás asignando `$start_date` a `$start_date_aux` y `$start_time` a `$start_time_aux`. Sin embargo, en lugar de crear una nueva instancia de `DateTime` para `$start_date_aux` y `$start_time_aux`, se crea una referencia a las variables originales. Esto significa que cualquier modificación realizada en `$start_date_aux` y `$start_time_aux` también afectará a las variables originales.

`$start_date_aux` y `$start_time_aux` se modifican:

```
while ($start_date_aux <= $end_date) {
    while ($start_time_aux < $end_time) {
        // ...
        $start_time_aux->add($time_interval);
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Estas modificaciones también se reflejarán en las variables originales `$start_date` y `$start_time`, ya que ambas son referencias a las mismas instancias de `DateTime`.

Debes clonar las instancias de `DateTime` en lugar de asignarlas directamente a las variables. Puedes hacerlo utilizando el método clone, de la siguiente manera:

```
$start_date_aux = clone $start_date;
$start_time_aux = clone $start_time;
```

[Referencia](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.cloning.php)

***Ejmplo:***

```
$start_date = new DateTime("2023-06-12");
$start_date_aux = clone $start_date;
$end_date = new DateTime("2023-06-13");
$start_time = new DateTime("08:00:00");
$start_time_aux = clone $start_time;
$end_time = new DateTime("21:00:00");
$time_interval = new DateInterval("PT30M");
```